# Checkboxes in Internet Explorer have "hover" view when are not hovered over

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox, hover

I have several *`checkbox lists`* and I need to update them every time when a user checks or *unchecks* any *checkbox*. Some of the lists may contain thousands of `checkboxes`.

Since creating of new elements is slow, I want to avoid it. Therefore, during the update, instead of deleting them, I save references to elements into a stack.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
// Save element to buffer. Each element looks like <div><input type="checkbox" /><label>label here</label></div>
while (checkBoxList.firstChild) {
    var div = checkBoxList.firstChild;
    buffer.push(div);
    checkBoxList.removeChild(div);
}

// elided ...

// Getting the new options...
// For each new option try to pop existing element from buffer or create new one if       buffer has no elements

var div = buffer.pop();
var divExists = div != undefined;
var checkBox = divExists ? div.firstChild : document.createElement('input');
var label = divExists ? div.lastChild : document.createElement('label');

checkBox.id = newId; // set new id
checkBox.name = newName; // set new name
checkBox.value = newValue // set new value

// elided...

// Append updated (or created one) to checkbox list
checkBoxList.appendChild(div);
```

This technique works fine, but in the `IE` I get the following issue: the `checkboxes` appear with blue color, as if mouse would hover over them *`(see the screenshot at http://postimage.org/image/z6yeckuz5/).`*

Have anyone faced similar issues? Why would this happen?

Comment: And what happens if you call `checkBox.blur()` on all of them, in addition to setting the `id` and such?

Comment: Why won't you use [documentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)? It is intended for this.

Comment: Thank you for comment. checkbox.blur() didn't made any difference. I will try to use documentFragment technique.

Comment: Well, how did it go? Did you solve your problem, and if you did, then how did that pan out? Can you add an answer, or close the question yet?